# How was Optimus Prime able to travel in space without a ship?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

Towards the end of *Transformers 4* Optimus Prime flew towards deep space without a ship, while in *Transformers 3*, the Autobots needed a big ship to travel to moon.

How is he able to do it? Was he upgraded?

Comment: Optimus Prime by himself isn't the same as the collective Autobots, so there's no reason to think he'd need to have been upgraded, or wasn't capable of doing whatever it is he does in Transformers 4 (I've only seen it once, and I don't remember much of it) in the previous movie. In Transformers 3 the point was to give the impression that *all of* the Autobots (who aren't necessarily capable of doing everything Optimus Prime was capable of doing) were *permanently leaving Earth*.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist what about the time when they were on the moon to retrieve the pillars? At that time they weren't showing anything they just need to use the shuttle to go to moon. If Optimus is so capable why didn't he go to the moon by himself.

Comment: Theres a difference between travelling and travelling in comfort.  Prime demonstrates several times that the transformers can travel in space without a ship, but having a ship gives you a lot more capability to do stuff on the journey and when you reach the destination.

Comment: @Moo great point. There is no physical, biological, or medical reason that a human could not walk all the way across the Sahara Desert, but it is a *lot* more pleasant in a vehicle, or at least on a camel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best guess is that Optimus obtained the rocket boosters when he pulled the sword of the [Knights' Temenos](https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Knights'_Temenos) from Lockdown's ship in the final act.

After pulling the sword where he said:

> Recognize one of your Knights.

He gained armor and most likely other upgrades (such as whatever allowed him to KO Grimlock with a right hook).

After (notice armored forearms):
[image: Transformer with armored forearms in a jungle landscape]

Before:

[image: Transformer without armored forearms in a rocky landscape]

<sup>This is the 2nd form we see Optimus in during the movie. The 1st is the junker truck.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because when he pulled the sword out of the Temenos, it upgraded his body to be more armored and turning his Pathblasters/ ultra Pathblaster into his shield/ultra Pathblaster; It also altered his legs and back so it could house thruster rocket jets in those parts of his body, this made it so he could fly without his trailer flight gear.  Also he was able to refuel on energon while he was on the ship he and the Autobots stole from Lockdown and freed the Dinobots from, so he had plenty of energon; and the speed and velocity at which he was moving meant he was able to move at the same speed as a rocket flying into space which is 7 miles per second or 25,000 miles per hour, fast enough to leave earth and fly to Jupiter and throw the seed into its atmosphere; as he did so, he decided to power down to a level where he could still function but conserve energy, and thanks to the speed he was going he could continue until he came back to Cybertron where he would power back up before landing.